# Why is modulus with unsigned int runs faster than with unsigned long long?

Tags: c, modulus, speed-test

### Why to test speed of modulus?

---

I have an app where modulus operation is performed millions times a second. I have to work with very big numbers, so I chose `unsigned long long` as a data type. About a week ago I've written a new algorithm for my app that required performing modulus operation on numbers which are *much less* than the numbers I used to work with (e.g. *26* instead of *10000000*). I chose to use `unsigned int` as a data type. *The speed increased dramatically* while the algorithm is almost the same.

### Testing...

---

I've written two simple programs in C to test the speed of modulus calculation.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned long long ull;

int main(){
   puts("Testing modulus with ull...");
   ull cnt;
   ull k, accum=0;
   for(k=1, cnt=98765432;k<=10000000;++k,--cnt) 
      accum+=cnt%80;
   printf("%llu\n",accum);
   return 0;
}
```

The only thing I was changing was the type of the variable called `cnt`.

I tested these programs with `time ./progname` and the results were as follows.

- With `unsigned long long`: *3.28 sec*
- With `unsigned int`: *0.33 sec*

**Note:** I'm testing it on a jailbroken iPad, that's why it takes so much time.

### Why?

---

Why does the version with `unsigned long long` take so much time to run?

**Update1:** added `--cnt` to the loop so `cnt%80` won't be constant; still the same results.

**Update2:** removed `printf` and added `accum` to get rid of time taken by `printf`; results are much less now but still pretty different.

Comment: Hint: `printf("%d vs %d", sizeof(unsigned int), sizeof(unsigned long long));`

Comment: The problem with printing in timing tests, is that you also test the timing of the printing. And console output is considerable slower than plain modulus.

Comment: @YuHao, to tell the truth, I expected the speed to be equal, but it turned out that it isn't...

Comment: This test program is invalid. The majority of its time is going to be spent in `printf`. And `cnt%80` has type `unsigned long long`, not `unsigned int`, so you can't print it with the `%u` specifier.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I've triple checked the results, they're always almost the same. The `printf` call is in both programs, so it shouldn't affect the results much.

Comment: @R.., I agree about the type of the result. At first I've been testing it with another variable of type `unsigned int`. I forgot to change the format specifier here.

Comment: How do you compile your program? Do you enable optimizations?

Comment: @dlask, I'm doing my best to force the compiler to remove any optimizations (with `gcc -O0 prog prog.c`)

Comment: without optimization result is meaningless. For the result, can you do a 4-digit division slower than a 8-bit one?

Comment: @ForceBru: That's your problem. If you're using `-O0` your results are nonsense. Switch to `-O2`, `-O3`, or `-Os`.

Comment: @R.., just did it. The timings became even worse: 16.7 with `ull` and 12.7 with `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, the amount of time it takes to perform an arithmetic operation scales *at least linearly* with the number of bits in the operands. For modern cpus, the time is constant (usually one cycle) for addition, subtraction, logical operations, and maybe multiplication when the operands fit in registers, but scale up to RSA order of magnitude or other "bignum" usage and you will clearly see how the time to perform arithmetic scales.

In the case of division and remainder operations, these are inherently more costly, and often you will notice a significant difference with different operand sizes. And of course if your cpu is 32-bit, doing a 64-bit division/remainder operation is going to involve constructing it out of multiple smaller operations (much like a small special-case of "bignum" arithmetic) so it's going to be considerably slower.

Your test, however, is just completely invalid. The division is constant so it should not even be recomputed on each loop iteration, the time spent in the loop should be dominated by `printf`, and the format specifier you're using with `printf` is not valid for printing arguments of type `unsigned long long`, so your program has undefined behavior.

Comment: I've updated the code so `cnt%80` won't be constant. I've also fixed the case with wrong format specifier in `printf`.

Comment: Having the `printf` in the loop is still dominating the time. Instead do something like `accum += cnt%80` on each iteration, then print `accum` after the loop. Also keep in mind that division/remainder with a constant divisor is going to have significantly different performance properties from division/remainder with a divisor that can vary at runtime.

Comment: just removed `printf` and added `accum`. Well, I didn't think `printf` can take _that_ much time...

Comment: You still have undefined behavior if you print `unsigned int` with `%llu` and only change the typedef. Anyway, the reason for slowness in long long was already answered. If you do it with bigint, the difference is even much bigger

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a 32bit system, the difference is in 64bit versus 32bit modulo operation.

```
ull cnt;
```

results in (using -O2 optimization):

```
.L2:
    pushl   $0
    pushl   $80
    pushl   %edi
    pushl   %esi
    call    __umoddi3           ; note the function call here
    addl    $16, %esp
    addl    %eax, -32(%ebp)
    adcl    %edx, -28(%ebp)
    addl    $-1, %esi
    movl    %esi, %eax
    adcl    $-1, %edi
    xorl    $88765432, %eax
    orl     %edi, %eax
    jne     .L2
    pushl   -28(%ebp)
    pushl   -32(%ebp)
    pushl   $.LC1
    pushl   $1
    call    __printf_chk
```

while

```
unsigned int cnt;
```

results in (using -O2 optimization too):

```
.L2:
    movl    %ecx, %eax
    mull    %ebx
    shrl    $6, %edx
    leal    (%edx,%edx,4), %eax
    movl    %ecx, %edx
    sall    $4, %eax
    subl    %eax, %edx
    movl    %edx, %eax
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    addl    %eax, %esi
    adcl    %edx, %edi
    subl    $1, %ecx
    cmpl    $88765432, %ecx
    jne     .L2
    pushl   %edi
    pushl   %esi
    pushl   $.LC1
    pushl   $1
    call    __printf_chk
```

Considering also the amount of code in the `__umoddi3` function we have the question answered.

Comment: the OP is using iPad, so it's ARM, not x86. But the point applies, dividing a 64-bit value is almost always slower than dividing a 32-bit one except on very strange architectures. The result assembly for ARM/ARM64 & x86/x86_64 can be seen [here](https://goo.gl/ZhaBBw)

Comment: In the case of ARM, there's generally no hardware divide instruction and division is performed by one long function that does it a bit at a time. Remainder is performed by dividing (with that function) then multiplying and subtracting.

Comment: And obviously a soft-div done one bit at a time is going to take considerably longer for 64 bits than for 32...

Comment: Thank you all for your clarification. My main intention was to demonstrate that arithmetic operations can take a lot of time if they don't have the appropriate hardware support. Anyway, I should have shown the ARM assembly code instead of the Intel one. Shall I change my answer?